# How to assert a IntegrityError properly in django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

folks. I'm trying to create a unit test to pass when an IntegrityError is raised.

I tried to do this but it tells me that IntegrityError is not iterable:

```
    def test_create_company_with_duplicate_cnpj(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError) as context:
            Company.objects.create(name=self.company.name, cnpj=self.company.cnpj)

        self.assertTrue('UNIQUE constraint failed' in context.exception)
```

I did the "workaround" below and it passed. But is it correct or is there a different solution without using pytest?

```
    def test_create_company_with_duplicate_cnpj(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            Company.objects.create(name=self.company.name, cnpj=self.company.cnpj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type cast the **`context.exception`** into a *string*, that is, use

```
'UNIQUE constraint failed' in str(context.exception)
```

Example:

```
def test_create_company_with_duplicate_cnpj(self):
    with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError) as context:
        Company.objects.create(name=self.company.name, cnpj=self.company.cnpj)

    self.assertTrue('UNIQUE constraint failed' in str(context.exception))
```